# Login Activity goes blank after login

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-login

I'm using facebook SDK for Android. I was making an app for about 3 days and today I wanted to test it with different facebook users accounts. So the first step is to log in, I'm asking for additional read permissions (read_requests, read_mailbox) and then for publish permissions (manage_notifications). Everything works fine when I'm logging into app as myself, firstly I see a webview with fields to log in, next I'm logging in and facebook is asking for additional permissions, but when I tried to do the same with different facebook accounts (my mates accounts) it's not working.
 It looks like this: I see a webview with login page I'm writing down name and password, clicking "log in" and then whole activity (which contains webview) goes blank (white), no errors in logcat, no errors from webview, anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you should clear  the facebook's shared preferences before new account log in from data->data->yourapp->Shared Prefs

Comment: I think it's not a problem because I tried uninstalling/installing app and clearing app's data and then logging in, but webview still goes blank after clicking "log in" button

Comment: Are you following the code in the SwitchUserSample that's shipped with the SDK? It shows you how to properly handle different accounts using the Session class.

Comment: I didn't see this example earlier, thanks! But I wonder because I don't want to allow switching between different accounts to my user, I just want to make it possible to log out and then log in to different account is there any easier way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with you. I solved the problem by the following methods.

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{      
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        if(url.startsWith("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth")){
           String redirectUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com/myReturnUrl";
            view.loadUrl(redirectUrl);
           return;
       }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }}
```

and  just add it to your WebView

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Before you can do this you have to check this first seems to be.
(app settings->basic->Mobile Web->Enter the return_url)

Comment: This doesnt seem to solve the problem. I have a fblogin function implemented in my website. But when I try to use it trough the web view it doesn't work. But if I use it trough the phones browser this works.